# Build Fail when using Stencils Event decorator

Tags: javascript, angular, stenciljs

I have a project using stencils and I want to send form input values to my other application that is written in Angular.
My project is working fine with stencils, but when I try to use the `@Event` decorator, it imediately fails on build.

Code:

```
// added Event and EventEmitter
import { Component, Method, Host, h, Prop, Event, EventEmitter } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: false,
})

export class MyComponent {
// some @Props
@Event({ eventName: 'a-click' }) onClick: EventEmitter<string>;

@Method()
  async handleClick(): Promise<void> {
    this.onClick.emit('hello world');
}
@Method()
async secondMethod(event: Event): Promise<void> {
  const { id } = (event.target as HTMLInputElement);
  // This handles a checkbox select/unselect
}

render() {...}
```

It all works fine, until I add the `@Event` decorator.
It fails without any message. There is only a red selection to the `Promise<void>` of second method. (but if I remove the event decorator, it all works). Any ideas why?

**EDIT**
If I remove my second method, using `Event`. It works.
is this some **CONFLICT**? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

That's a known issue of Stencil (or perhaps TypeScript), but there is a simple workaround ([from the docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/events#event-decorator)):

> In the case where the Stencil Event type conflicts with the native web Event type, it is suggested that the native web Event type be prefixed with globalThis:
>
> ```
> @Event() myEvent: EventEmitter<{value: string, ev: globalThis.Event}>;
> ```

More details:

- https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/4681
- https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/3037
- https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/3137